# GIT: restoring server with remote git repository - how to act right?

Tags: git, backup

The machine where our remote-repositories are stored crashed. Currently it is restored with a two-day old backup.

Can you give us some advice on what to do?
In our opinion, all we need to do is push our local commits in all branches back to the remote-repo.

Are we oversseing something here?
Any advice would be appreciated!

Kind regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there was a need to restore the remote. You could simply push your local repo to a new remote one. That's one of the reasons that made distributed source control so popular, isn't it?